# Custom breadcrumb for masterpage and list libraries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

i have hit an issue which has thrown me a little. I have set my list libraries masterpage to my custom masterpage but i need to show a beeadcrumb through out the site which also works with list libraries. Can anyone explain or point me to a solition which provides a breadcrumb accross all of sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Create a custom control

Comment: I find the top links of this search helpful: https://www.google.com/search?q=sp+2013+breadcrumb

Comment: Hi Alexey the OOTB breadcrumb doesnt provide list library navigation.